# Text Mesh Pro edges are not smooth when viewed by orthographic camera

Tags: unity, antialiasing, text-mesh-pro, minimap

I have a minimap camera (orthographic camera) which is rendering text mesh pro but the problem is the text edges are not smooth. Here is the screenshot:

[[image]

The camera orthographic rendering on render texture.

Edit:

Some basic Orthogrphic camera setting are:

```
transform.localPosition = new Vector3(-26853f, 1165f, 24669f);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(90f, -175.45f, 0f);
            miniMapCamera.orthographicSize = 110000;
```

Here is my text mesh pro, inspector:
[[image]

Text mesh pro font size is 80.

Comment: You've been here long enough to know we need a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example. Walk us through the Text Mesh Pro setup so we can reproduce this problem in a new empty project.

Comment: you are absolutely right. But what else required. Text Mesh pro is a pretty standard tool.

Comment: I have added some images for more clarification.

Comment: We can't see the font size you've configured here or the size the font material was generated with.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that there is a problem with your set up because you scale up the text, and that should not really be necessary. Here my result and its set up made using your camera settings:

[image: End result]

[image: Camera settings]

[image: Canvas settings]

[image: Text settings]

[image: Text settings]

As you can see the text is quite big, so I need to scale it down, not up, and not necessarily because I can make a ton of other adjustments before to have to go touch the scale.

Also, judging from your settings, here you are actually rendering a terrain. That is not really a good idea because it'd have a strong performance impact. Usually, for real-time map generation, you take a picture of the terrain in the 1024x1024 size or in any other acceptable texture size (not too high and without any MipMap) and you use that for your MiniMap, computing the scaled positions of the objects and player to show their representation. Even better, you create a stylised map in Photoshop in the correct scale to your terrain and use that.

**EDIT:**
In case of the 3D Text Pro (no Canvas) then avoid scaling that much by delegating the scaling to Text Mesh Pro font engine. To do that create a copy of the original SDF (or generate a new one) then set the scaling in the SDF inspector as shown in the following image:
[image: Scaling the font in the SDF asset file]

Comment: I am not using canvas text mesh pro. It is 3d text mesh pro

Comment: The 3D version is a bit of a pain in the neck :) You might need to increase the SDF scale to improve the text for such highly scaled text renderer. To do so, create a duplicate of the SDF file you are using, and set its scale to 3 or higher (you have to test a bit) so that you don't have to scale the 3D object that much, leaving the scaling to Text Mesh Pro engine.

Comment: Here an example of that setting. I'm adding it to the answer as well: https://i.gyazo.com/f80075e8cc0f8f9acd17a6d88b2780fa.png